# Overflow text should dynamically resize the container

Tags: jquery, css

I have added one image (it is a nice painted box type thing rectangular shape) on my webpage. I placed some text on that.

Now when I open it in smaller resolution screens, the text is coming out of the box vertically. I want to stop that and make the jog box (I mean here div) stretchable vertically according to text.

Is there any simple way to accomplish this?

**Edit:** The body tag goes like this

```
<body>
<div .class="container">
    <img src="pic.jpg" class="pic" alt="">
    <h2>some lenghty text</h2>
</body>
```

and the CSS goes here

```
.pic {
    /* because as the pic is very large and need to center that */
    width:40%; 
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    display:block;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin_left:auto;
    top:200px;
    position:relative;
}

h2 {
    position:absolute;
    font-size:20px;
    font-color:blue;
}
```

So with the above piece of code I am not achieving what I want i.e if the  text length increases (in some small screens or while resized), the container i.e jpg should be prolonged vertically down the screen so that the  text sits nicely inside that box image itself

Comment: @Vivek, if it's coming out of the box, setting overflow will only change how the overflowing text is displayed (or not displayed). It won't cause the box to stretch.

Comment: Please use the `{}` code button, and take a second to read up on how to format your question correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Most likely the div was given a fixed height. If you "inspect element" on the div using firebug or chrome, you should be able to hunt down the CSS rule that sets this height. Then either remove that rule, or change `height:` to `min-height:`.</strike>

Update:

The problem is that the div **is** expanding, but the image is not. Until the CSS3 `background-size` property is well supported, you can simply set the height of the img to 100%:

```
img.pic {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks box9,but i dint keep any height tag in css,please check my modified code for css i have used...

Comment: @simple-coder, I don't see any CSS. It is also possible that some javascript is setting the CSS height. The best way to check is by inspecting the element in firebug and chrome (both the CSS side-panel and the inline `style` attribute). If you're still sure the height isn't being set somewhere, then posting some HTML and CSS in your question would help ;)

Comment: am sorry box9,i have just added now...can u have a look

Comment: @simple-coder, Ok the problem is very different now. The div **is** expanding, but the image is fixed. I'll update my answer shortly.